# Repeat a Powershell Script Untill done

Tags: powershell

I am writing a Script, to restart multiple computers at once.

I am trying to make it as human-like behavior, once computers are rebooted it will ping and check if computers are coming back, but I want it keeps pinging back the computers which didn't come up for 10 minutes and at last if not response it says that something went wrong with this computer and didn't come back.

also if you see this line, I'm importing computers back again to test connecting after rebooting is it possible not to do so and tested connection only those computers which are rebooted.Thanks.

```
 Start-Sleep -Seconds 120   
    $coms=GC c:\restarted.txt
```

complete script.

```
$computers=GC c:\list.txt
         ForEach ($computer in $computers)
{if((Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)){
       Try {
Restart-computer -ComputerName $computer -force -ErrorAction stop
Write-Host "Restarting $computer" -f green
$($computer)|Out-File c:\restarted.txt -append
}
Catch {
[system.exception]
Write-Warning "Failed to restart $($computer) `n$error[0]"
}
}
else {
     Write-Host "cannot reach $computer and cannot restart" -BackgroundColor red
     }
     }  

     ## wait for 2 Minutes to check if the computer is coming back!
Start-Sleep -Seconds 120   
$coms=GC c:\restarted.txt
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
ForEach ($com in $coms)
{if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $com -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
        {write-host "$com still booting" -f red}

else {

        Write-Host "$com is coming back !" -f Green
     }
     }
```

Comment: Check for Do While or Do Until loop. PS is having both the options

Answer (score 0):

> I want it keeps pinging back the computers which didn't come up for
>   10 minutes and at last if not response it say that, something went
>   wrong with this computer and didn't came back

- [`do-while` loop](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/05/powershell-looping-understanding-and-using-do-while/)

> im importing computers back again to test connecting after rebooting
>   is it possible not to do so and tested connection only those computers
>   which are rebooted

- Some kind of variable to hold the list of computers - e.g [`[Array]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-5.1)

---

```
$computers = GC c:\list.txt

ForEach ($computer in $computers){
    if((Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)){

        Try{
            Restart-computer -ComputerName $computer -force -ErrorAction stop
            Write-Host "Restarting $computer" -f green
            $computer | Out-File c:\restarted.txt -append
            [array]$restartedComputers += $computer          # store restarted computers is variable here
        }Catch [system.exception] { # typo: type should come before opening curly brace
            Write-Warning "Failed to restart $($computer) `n$error[0]"
        }

    }else{

        Write-Host "cannot reach $computer and cannot restart" -BackgroundColor red

    }

}  

## wait for 2 Minutes to check if the computer is coming back!
Start-Sleep -Seconds 120

ForEach ($com in $restartedComputers){

    # set the end time as ten minutes from now
    $endTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(10)

    # for 10 minutes, try to ping.
    do{

        if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $com -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet)){

            # if it fails, set $online to false and wait 30 seconds.
            Write-Host "$com still booting" -f red
            $online = $false
            Start-Sleep -s 30

        }else{
            # if it works, set $online to true and exit from this do-while loop
            Write-Host "$com is coming back !" -f Green
            $online = $true
            return;
        }

    }while((Get-Date) -lt $endTime)

    # check whether the computer was contacted in the end.
    if(-not $online){
        # tried to ping for 10minutes and failed: do stuff.
    }

    # move on to next computer.
}
```

Comment: hey sorry for being late Thanks for reply I will try that

Comment: Not working as expected [array]$restartedComputers += $computer    stores only 1 computer and after restart it only pings the computer which is online and stops